# Ruby Conditional Assignment with Zero

Tags: ruby

Easy one for you: What's the Ruby equivalent of this in PHP?

```
return $x == 0 ? 1 : $x;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same

```
 x == 0 ? 1 : x
```

The `||=` shortcut is not applicable here, because 0 is not a "falsy" value, it's `true`.

Comment: Doh! Thanks! I thought I tried that but obviously not! Yes I was expecting `||=` to work as PHP would too.

Comment: However, in Ruby, `if` is an *expression*, not a statement (in fact, *everything* is an expression in Ruby, there are no statements), so the use of the conditional operator is never necessary, and using `if` is often more readable: `if x == 0 then 1 else x end`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: It depends. In this situation I find ternary operator much more readable. It's a matter of taste and background, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that `$x` is a `Numeric`, then:

```
$x.zero? ? 1 : $x
```